# Freeman & Tukey interval

Tags: confidence-interval, poisson-distribution

If $Y$ is $\text{Poisson}(λ)$ distributed, how do we obtain this confidence interval for $λ$:

$\:l=\frac14 [(\sqrt{Y}+\sqrt{Y+1}-z_{α/2} )^2-1]$

$u=\frac14 [(\sqrt{Y}+\sqrt{Y+1}+z_{α/2} )^2-1]$